# How to maintain Ember Data two-way binding when using DataTables?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatables, ember-data

I am working on a project using Ember and I have a table component. which is created in HTML/Handlebars and initialized as a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) using jquery.

When initialised as a Datatable, the table is no longer responsive to the refreshModel: true of the queryParams on the page and the two way binding of Ember Data is lost. This is important functionality for me so I wondered if there was a way to have the best of both worlds?

The jquery in the component.js is:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({

  model: null,

  didInsertElement() {
    let table = $('#resultsTable').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      paging: false,
      scrollY: 500
    });


  },

});
```

The table is correct on the initial render but changing one of my queryParams does not refresh the data. I tried to rerender as follows:

```
  didUpdateAttrs() {
    let table = $('#resultsTable').DataTable({
      destroy: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
    });
  }
```

This works to some extent but produces some undesirable behavior such as the table updating but not updating the 'Showing x results' widgets or taking a long time to update. If do not destroy the table I receive an error like:

```
DataTables warning: table id={id} - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
```

Which is a limitation of the Datatables library described [here](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3)

Thoughts welcome

Comment: using an [ember table component](https://emberobserver.com/categories/lists-and-tables)  is not an option? It will be quite a pain to combine this, while its so easy to do this all in ember.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the killer feature for my use case with Datatables is the easy ability to create CSV, XLS and PDF files using its buttons library, I don't think ember-table or ember-light-table has similar functionality does it?

Comment: it confuses me that CSV, XLS and PDF creation are connected to an visual display library. usually you can do this quite independent of each other. To generale CSV is easy, and for XLS there are [libraries](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). PDF depends a bit on the formatting, but a solution could be just to use the print feature. Also there are libraries. Also you probably can extract the pdf/csv/xls code form datatables.

Comment: the seems to use [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) for pdfs. Would love to see an ember addon to do all this tho :p